# SQL Server 2012: why does full-text search not index .pdf, .cs?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have installed SQL Server 2012, then executed

```
select document_type 
from sys.fulltext_document_types
```

The result is 50 extensions, ok.

Then I downloaded FilerPack SP2 from Microsoft site, installed it, executed

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'load_os_resources', 1
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages'
```

restarted SQL Server and executed:

```
select document_type 
from sys.fulltext_document_types
```

The result is 151 extensions including .pdf, .cs and so on.

Then:

```
create table DocumentRepository
(
    id int not null primary key identity,
    fileName nvarchar(250),
    fileSize int,
    fileExtension NVARCHAR(10),
    attachment varbinary(max)
);
GO

GRANT INSERT,UPDATE,SELECT,DELETE on DocumentRepository to public;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FTSCatalog AS DEFAULT;
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.DocumentRepository
(fileName, attachment TYPE COLUMN fileExtension)
KEY INDEX PK__Document__3213E83FEFB4F2B9
ON FTSCatalog
WITH CHANGE_TRACKING AUTO;
GO
```

And added some files: .pdf, .txt, .cs, .docx

- Microsoft Project Silk.pdf 7963 .pdf
- kdd-camera-ready-final.pdf 354 .pdf
- pro_wcf_4_2nd_edition.pdf 22193 .pdf
- dbw.txt 3 .txt
- mydoc.docx 11 .docx
- RollingFileAppender.cs 50 .cs

And finally executed:

```
select * 
from DocumentRepository 
where contains(*, N'Firefox') 

------
0, (word inside pdf field)

select * 
from DocumentRepository 
where contains(*, N'Appender')

-----
0, (word inside .cs)

select * 
from DocumentRepository 
where contains(*, N'database')

--------
dbw.txt 3   .txt
mydoc.docx  11  .docx
```

Why does FTS not search in `.pdf`, `.cs` files?